# Multiple Column binding issue with ObjectList

Tags: c#, asp.net

I Have used objectlist to display data like a grid for mobile. but when the page is shown on mobile(Black berry device) it displays just one column which is given in the LabelField property.

below is my sample snip of the code

```
<mobile:ObjectList ID="objLst" Runat="server" CommandStyle-StyleReference="subcommand"
                                                      Font-Size="Small" AutoGenerateFields="true" 
                                                        TableFields="Location;Date;Amount;DocID"                                                       
                                                        OnItemCommand="objLst_ItemCommand" OnItemSelect="objLst_ItemSelect" 
                                                        ItemsPerPage="10"    >

                                                        <Field DataField="Location" Name="Location" Title="Location" Visible="true" />            
                                                        <Field DataField="Date" Name="Date" Title="Date" Visible="true" />
                                                        <Field DataField="Amount" Name="Amount" Title="Amount" Visible="true" />                                                       
                                                         <Field DataField="DocID" Name="DocID" Title="DocID" Visible="true" />                                                       
                                                        <Command Name="Edit" Text="Edit" />                           
                                                    </mobile:ObjectList>
```

in Page Load event i've binded the list

```
objLst.DataSource = dt ;// Data table with default Values
objLst.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To all I have found that some device browsers are not able to show ObjectList control. This is what i found after doing RND on Multiple device.